# Excel Formula to return a number based on product name and latest date

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am looking for help with an Excel formula. What I need is to return the chemical and quantity with the latest date in another table showing the chemical and quantity.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a few table of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to put the whole output table into an array that spills.  With Office 365 you can do this LET formula:

```
=LET( a, A5:C19,
       f, FILTER( a, INDEX( a, , 1) <> "" ),
       c, INDEX( f, , 1), q, INDEX( f, , 2), d, INDEX( f, , 3),
       sf, SORTBY(f,c,1,d,1),
       CHOOSE( {1,2}, UNIQUE( c ), XLOOKUP( UNIQUE( c ), c, q,, 0,-1 ) ) )
```

where you input your entire range of Chemical, Quantity and Actual Date values into a variable called **a**. The rest of the formula creates a sorted lookup table and then searches your left side filter formula to find the last match.

[image: result]

Comment: This workes great. Thank you so very much.

Comment: @CLPowell - cool. If it is the answer, can you please mark it as the answer?